# How regex engine finds first match position

Tags: regex

Need to understand how to realize pattern searching in regex engine. I find several simple realizations for Regex engine (for example https://github.com/cable729/Regex/blob/master/tests/ComplexRegexTests.java)
and they has no method "find", only "accept", that returns true/false as result of *whole* string matching.

But how to find index of first entry?
Apply regex for every char in input string untill it was matched or all string was consumed by regex? - I don't believe that regex engines do so.

How they do it?

Comment: That's essentially what they do. Sometimes optimizations are possible: If the regex is anchored, you don't have to try every position; if the regex starts with a fixed string, you can do a string search to find potential match positions, etc.

Comment: Thank you, it is now clear what to do, because I don't need to look for unknown algorithms.

Comment: It turns out, in the world some trick exists for true NFA (with no backtracking, but with the groups capturing) - just using ^(.*?)(pattern).

But NFA without backtracking runs over 20 times slower than non-compiled .NET NFA in non-pathological cases and backreferences can't be implemented.

So, I still don't know no how it works, but I stupidly did copy-paste the Regex code from mono